# Checking if spinner is selected and having null value in Android

Tags: android, spinner

I want to check first if spinner has null values based on the following:

```
String Name= spinnerName.getSelectedItem().toString();
if(Name != null) {     
} else { 
}
```

is this a proper way? because i get 
`FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.NullPointerException` on

```
String Name= spinnerName.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

I have declared it on Create

Comment: @MD:Getting NPE exception in `String Name= spinnerName.getSelectedItem().toString();` means `spinnerName` is `null`. so think comparing string is another problem

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`spinnerName` is null or if `getSelectedItem()` returns null, calling `toString()` will cause your app to crash for NPE

```
String name= null;
if(spinnerName != null && spinnerName.getSelectedItem() !=null ) {
   name = (String)spinnerName.getSelectedItem();
} else  { 

}
```

Comment: one question i have a three spinner and check there condition what should i do??

Answer (score 4):

```
if (spinner1.getCount()==0){
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"spinner hasn't values",               
   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Function for `Spinner` Item Selection

```
SpinnerName.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {             
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v,int position, long id) {
                // On selecting a spinner item
                selected_item = adapter.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            }
});
```

Check condition for `selected Item`

```
if(selected_item.matches("")){
          //conditions accordingly  
return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first you have to check either any item in the spinner selected or not and initialized or not

```
if (modeOfReportingSpinner.getSelectedItem()!=null){
        modeOfString = modeOfReportingSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not add `toString()`. If you add `toString()` it tries to convert `null` to `String`, then it throws `Exception`.

```
if(spinnerName.getSelectedItem() !=null ) {
   name = spinnerName.getSelectedItem().toString();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can define a spinner for departure and destination like you did there, then inside a button `onClickListener` you can check for the value before starting a new activity for example:

```
if(spinner1.getSelectedItem.toString.equalIgnoreCase(value) && spinner2.getSelectedItem.toString.equalIgnoreCase(value)) {
    Intent mIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailActivity.class) startActivity(mIntent); 
}else{ 
    //Show Toast here
```