# if spinner value is null, set the button unclicable

Tags: android

I cant find a reason why this is not working. I am trying to achive that if all 3 spinners dont have anything selected then you cant click save. I came up with this code. The spinners are populated from xml file.

Spinner:

```
 spinner_pain = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinner_mypain);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this.getActivity(), R.array.spinner_mypain, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner_pain.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Condition:

```
   if (spinner_pain.getSelectedItem() == null && spinner_medicine.getSelectedItem() == null && spinner_dailyInput.getSelectedItem() == null) {
                shrani_nastavitve.setClickable(false);
            }
```

Comment: What happens currently?

Comment: it does not work, the button is clickable

Comment: Have you debugged to see why your `if` statement is not fulfilled?

Comment: when do you call it?

Comment: what makes you think the button is clickable? There is a difference between clickable and enabled. If a button is not clickable, then no code is executed but the button still shows like it is clicked. Means, it looks like the click is successfull, but the button doesn´t listen to, only the GUI reacts. If you use setEnabled(false), then also the graphical Button click is not reacting.

Answer (score 0):

you should set enable to false

```
button.setEnabled(false);
```

or implement onClickLister and set it null

```
button.setOnClickListener(this);//working
button.setOnClickListener(null);//NOT working
```

Comment: nothing works i think the problem must be in my if sentence

Comment: then you can check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29891237/checking-if-spinner-is-selected-and-having-null-value-in-android