# Combining Spinner and Button onClick Listener is giving me a Null Pointer exception

Tags: java, android, android-studio, nullpointerexception, android-spinner

I have an app where a person will be allowed to post an announcement. The person has to select on the spinner the category of their announcement and type their announcement on an `EditText`. After entering both these fields the Button will allow the person to make the Announcement but if the spinner value or the `EditText` Value is empty an Error should be generated. I tried making the button invisible for the person typing the Announcement because i was getting a `Null Pointer Exception` but after switching to, making the button invisible I still get the same Error. This is my Code:

```
public class MakeAnnouncements extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText announcement;
private Button announce_button;
private ProgressDialog announcementDialog;
private DatabaseReference mRootRef;

private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private String mCurrentUserId;
private String announcer;
private String []SPINNERCATEGORY ={"General","Cubs","Scouts","Seniors"};
private String category_text;

private MaterialBetterSpinner betterSpinner;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_make_announcements);

    announcementDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    mRootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mCurrentUserId =  mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    announcement = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.announce_text);
    announce_button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.announce_btn);

    announce_button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,SPINNERCATEGORY);
    betterSpinner = (MaterialBetterSpinner)findViewById(R.id.category_spinner);


    betterSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

            String spinner_value= adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            if(position==0){
                // no item selected show Toast message
                announce_button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } else{
                announce_button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                // item selected
            }

                category_text = spinner_value;


            return;
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            announce_button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        }
    });


    betterSpinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);


    mRootRef.child("Users").child(mCurrentUserId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            announcer = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


    announce_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {  //<----- This is where i am getting a null point exception 

            String announced_text = announcement.getText().toString().trim();
            String choosen_category = category_text.trim();



            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(announced_text)){

                announcement.setError("You did not type any announcement");

                return;


            }



            announcementDialog.setTitle("Posting Announcement...");
            announcementDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            announcementDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            announcementDialog.show();
            PostAnnouncement(announced_text,choosen_category);
        }
    });
}

private void PostAnnouncement(String announced_text, String choosen_category) {



    DatabaseReference chat_push_key = mRootRef.child("Announcements").child(announcer).push();

    String push_key = chat_push_key.getKey();

    Map messageMap = new HashMap();
    messageMap.put("announcement",announced_text);
    messageMap.put("type","text");
    messageMap.put("category",choosen_category);
    messageMap.put("from",announcer);
    messageMap.put("time", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);

    Map messageUserMap = new HashMap();
    messageUserMap.put( "Announcements" + "/" + push_key, messageMap);

    announcement.setText("");
    announcementDialog.hide();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your announcement was successfully posted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    mRootRef.updateChildren(messageUserMap, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {

            if(databaseError != null){

                Log.d("CHAT_LOG", databaseError.getMessage().toString());

            }

        }
    });



}
}
```

What am i required to do to validate if the spinner Value is not empty?

Comment: With spinner you always have the first value selected by default

Comment: But the first value is null and if nothing is entered it, i get the NullPointerException

Comment: @BrijeshJoshi can you please look at my solution

Answer (score 0):

According to your code you can check on the variable **`category_text`**.

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(category_text)){
    //Show your error message
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After checking for possible ways to solve this [This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29891237/checking-if-spinner-is-selected-and-having-null-value-in-android) assisted me.
I first changed the spinner_value to be a global variable. Then wrote this code:

```
    String announced_text = announcement.getText().toString().trim();
    String choosen_category = null;

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(announced_text)){

            announcement.setError("You did not type any announcement");

            return;


        }
         if(spinner_value != null){
            choosen_category = spinner_value.trim();

           return;
         }
          else if(spinner_value == null){

           betterspinner.setError("This section must be selected before proceeding");

           return;

          }
```

After that i removed button Visibilities that are in my initial code.

Comment: But then after selecting one spinner value i get an error for both when nothing is selected and when some value is selected